# How To Remove Excel VBA's $ sign from code

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code:

```
Sub poorguy()
Dim counter As Long
Dim countto As Long
Dim col1 As String
Dim col2 As String
Dim col3 As String
Dim col4 As String
Dim rngwrite As Range

counter = 0
countto = 100

For i = 0 To countto
    col1 = Cells(12, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col2 = Cells(12, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col3 = Cells(3, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col4 = Cells(3, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address
    Set rngwrite = Cells(58, 3).Offset(counter, counter)
    rngwrite.Value = "=(" & col1 & "-" & col2 & ")*" & col3 & "*" & col4
    counter = counter + 1
Next
Set rngwrite = Nothing
End Sub
```

The problem is that it generates too many $ in the formula. For example,
it gives: `=($B$12-$C$12)*$B$3*$C$3`

What I want is: `=($B$12-C12)*$B$3*C3`

How do I remove the extra $'s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add (false, false) to the address you do not want absolute values for.

```
Sub poorguy()
Dim counter As Long
Dim countto As Long
Dim col1 As String
Dim col2 As String
Dim col3 As String
Dim col4 As String
Dim rngwrite As Range

counter = 0
countto = 100

For i = 0 To countto
    col1 = Cells(12, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col2 = Cells(12, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address(false, false)
    col3 = Cells(3, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col4 = Cells(3, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address(false, false)
    Set rngwrite = Cells(58, 3).Offset(counter, counter)
    rngwrite.Value = "=(" & col1 & "-" & col2 & ")*" & col3 & "*" & col4
    counter = counter + 1
Next
Set rngwrite = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get rid of all `$` characters in your string with `Replace`, after it's been set with the address but before it's used to create the formula:

```
col2 = Replace(col2, "$", "")
```

(and ditto for `col4`).

Alternatively, the first two arguments to `Address` dictate whether the row and column portion are generated as relative (false) or absolute (true, the default). That gives more more fine-grained control over the generated string.